# Grep to check filesystem mount and test to check for file path is providing incorrect information

Tags: bash, grep, test

Even though the path exists, this script reports that it does not. What is the flaw in the logic?

```
#!/bin/bash
mount="/fileserver"

if grep -qs "$mount" /proc/mount && { test -d '/fileserver/subdirectory'; } then
 echo "Both the mount and path exist."
else grep -qs "$mount" /proc/mount ! && { test -d '/fileserver/subdirectory'; }
 echo "mount exists, but path does not."
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is quite right, but the negation operator to use along with the `&&` is in wrong place altogether, it needs to be alongside the `test` operator.

With your command in question the first part of the `if` condition is evaluated as below,

```
grep -qs "$mount" /proc/mount !
```

in which the negation operator is treated as an another file to search on by the `grep` which would have resulted in `grep: !: No such file or directory`, but because of the error suppress flags on file non-existence (`-s`) the errors are not shown in the terminal.

Also the `{..}` compound operator is not needed as long as you have a single command. You just need to do below:

```
if grep -qs "$mount" /proc/mount &&  test -d "/fileserver/subdirectory";  then
    echo "Both the mount and path exist."
else grep -qs "$mount" /proc/mount && ! test -d "/fileserver/subdirectory"; then
    echo "mount exists, but path does not."
fi
```

That said, you don't need to silence the output of `grep` right away until you assert the script is working. Try running it without the `-qs` flags for an added debug step.

---

You can also use [mountpoint(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mountpoint) tool from the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package using which you can directly check if a path is mounted

```
if mountpath -q "/fileserver/subdirectory"; then
```

Comment: Very good, @inian.  +1.  I would also point out (1) while in the process of debugging code, it is best not to silence the error messages as the `-qs` options do on the `grep` command, and (2) on Linux, `mountpoint -q "$mount"` is generally superior to grepping `/proc/mount`.  (`mountpoint` is part of the util-linux package.)